# Android link issue

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I try to compile C++ code on Android.

android-api=21
android-ndk=r14b

I got this error :

```
8-02 17:33:32.926 30669-30669/com.example.user.mod2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.user.mod2, PID: 30669
                                                                          java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev" referenced by "/data/app/com.example.vkhadir.mod2-1/lib/arm/libcustom.so"...
                                                                              at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
                                                                              at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                                              at com.example.user.mod2.MainActivity.load(MainActivity.java:65)
                                                                              at com.example.user.mod2.MainActivity.loadlibs(MainActivity.java:37)
                                                                              at com.example.user.mod2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

The issue come from `ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev` (aka`ios_base::Init::~Init` ), when I check `libc++_shared.so` file in android standalone toolchain, `nm -D` only find `_ZNSt6__ndk18ios_base4InitD1Ev`.

Where did  `ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev` come from and how can I get it ?

Comment: Is `libc++_shared.so` packaged in the APK?

Comment: The issue seem to happen during packaging. linking `libc++_shared.so` raise no error but linking our custom code raise symbol not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your library is built against a different version of libc++ than the one you've shipped. `ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev` is the name prior to r11. It's been `_ZNSt6__ndk18ios_base4InitD1Ev` since then.

Alternatively, your library is built against gnustl or stlport but ships libc++.

Comment: thanks I'll investigate more, that strange I use r14b to compile everything

Comment: It seem the problem come from gnustl. I use a lib that is compiled with `arm-linux-androideabi-4.9`

Comment: I validate your answer even if I was not able to find a solution yet.

Comment: Is your whole app being built every time? No prebuilt middleware? If you have some third-party dependencies it could be caused by them.

Comment: In fact I use two libraries, compiled from source. Opencv which can only be compiled with gcc/gnustl and Mxnet that can only be compile with clang/libc++ :(

Comment: Unfortunately the two libraries are incompatible then. All your libraries need to use the same STL.